# How to return data at specific order - randomized order that listed at where clause at select

Tags: sql-order-by

SELECT Cellphone, FirstName, LastName FROM Players where PlayerID in (10,2,3,8,66,1)

If I want that data will be returned at order that written at 'where', so the first PlayerID is 10 and the second one 2, third 3... and the last one is 1.
How I can do it? ASC or DESC will not help me, because its randomized order.